# SQL Server query to create database is giving me an error when I include numeric characters in the database name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, identifier

I am having trouble running a simple sql query in **Microsoft SQL Server 2005** to create a database and im not sure why.

When I run this query

```
CREATE DATABASE 4444-virtual2
```

I receive this error

> Incorrect syntax near '4444'.

Is there anything in particular that I must specify if I am creating a database table with numeric values in the name? Or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Database names need to [start with a letter, underscore, at sign or number sign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx):

> The first character must be one of the
>   following:
>
> - A letter as defined by the Unicode
>     Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition
>     of letters includes Latin characters
>     from a through z, from A through Z,
>     and also letter characters from other
>     languages.
> - The underscore (_), at sign (@), or
>     number sign (#).
>
> Certain symbols at the beginning of an
>   identifier have special meaning in SQL
>   Server. A regular identifier that
>   starts with the at sign always denotes
>   a local variable or parameter and
>   cannot be used as the name of any
>   other type of object. An identifier
>   that starts with a number sign denotes
>   a temporary table or procedure. An
>   identifier that starts with double
>   number signs (##) denotes a global
>   temporary object. Although the number
>   sign or double number sign characters
>   can be used to begin the names of
>   other types of objects, we do not
>   recommend this practice.
>
> Some Transact-SQL functions have names
>   that start with double at signs (@@).
>   To avoid confusion with these
>   functions, you should not use names
>   that start with @@.

Unless you want to delimit every use of the name with double quotes `"4444-virtual2"` or brackets `[4444-virtual2]`.

Answer (score 7):

You can still create a database with that name, but you need to put it in quotes or brackets.  e.g. this works:

```
CREATE DATABASE [4444-virtual2]
```

or this:

```
CREATE DATABASE "4444-virtual2"
```